# Как склеить два списка в один двумерный

Tags: python, список

Ребятки, помогите допетрить.
Как склеить два списка в один двумерный, чтобы получилась следующая картина:

```
Massiv1 = ['Stroka 1', 'Stroka 2', ...дальше много строк...]


Massiv2 = [100, 200, ......]
```

---некий код, где склеиваются Massiv1 и Massiv2---

Результат:

```
Massiv_sum = [['Stroka 1', 100],['Stroka 2', 200],.... и так далее ....]
```

Answer (score 2):

Для решения задачи необходимо использовать функцию `zip`:

```
Massiv1 = ['Stroka 1', 'Stroka 2']
Massiv2 = [100, 200]
Massiv_sum = list(zip(Massiv1, Massiv2))
Massiv_sum_result = []

for m_item in Massiv_sum:
    Massiv_sum_result.append(list(m_item))
```

`zip` здесь это [застёжка-молния](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper)—сшивает две половинки:

[image: zipper]

Comment: Ваш результат отличается от необходимого - нужен список списков, а у вас на выходе список кортежей.

Comment: @Эникейщик Обновил пример. Но ниже уже предложили более элегантный код

Comment: @jfs Картинка подходит идеально, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Здесь пригодится функция `zip()`. Но она возвращает кортеж из элементов списка, поэтому функцией `list` нужно превратить каждый полученный кортеж в список:

```
Massiv_sum = [list(a) for a in zip(Massiv1, Massiv2)]
```

Результат:

```
[['Stroka 1', 100], ['Stroka 2', 200]]
```